# Store incoming sms number in server(TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, django

Newbie to python and django. I have a ideal to develop a sms marketing campaign. I'm using Twilio Api, Django framework, django_twilio. I will be sending out mass text messages introducing my business and will allow subscriptions to different types of offers based on keyword responses. I've been able to send out the messages and pull the number from the respondents. I'm puzzled about how would I code taking those numbers and store them in the database in a way that would have those who want to subscribe to one offer in a viewable listing and those who want to subscribe to other offers in their own viewable list. I have little experience, but so far this is what Ive manage to get on my own. By "viewable list" I intend to keep count of how subscribers I have for each offer so that i can present to my clients as to say "I Have this {} many subscribers to your offer"

views.py

```
from django.http import request
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from django_twilio.request import decompose
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from .models import OfferListing

@twilio_view
def sms_choice(request):
twilio_request = decompose(request)
contact_num = twilio_request.from_
response = twilio_request.body
resp = MessagingResponse()

if response == 'Doctor':
    OfferListing(doctor_list=contact_num)
    resp.message('Thanks for subscribing')

elif response == 'Dentist':
    OfferListing(dentist_list=contact_num)
    resp.message('Thanks for subscribing')

print(contact_num, response)
return str(resp)
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models

#Available Listing


class OfferListing (models.Model):
    doctor_list = [models.BigAutoField()]
    dentist_list = [models.BigAutoField()]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self

#Customer Numbers


class Contacts (models.Model):
    number = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self


#Based on response add contact to Offerlistings

class Subscription (models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey('OfferListing',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='number_sub')

    choice = models.ManyToManyField(OfferListing)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: Just wanted to throw this out there: make sure you are following all applicable laws when it comes to 'mass texting'. You can get in a lot of trouble for spamming people or not allowing them to opt out depending on where you are located.

Comment: Thanks and yes I'm aware of the laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend 3 models: a table with the phone number you texted and any info about that person you have, a table with the available 'lists' you offer, and a 3rd table that foreign keys to both of those tables. This can change depending on if a person can belong to multiple lists. In that case, you would need a manytomany model.

You don't want to have a different model for each list. Imagine your business takes off and you have to maintain 500 different lists (doctor, dentist, vet, OBGYN, ENT, Cardio, neuro, etc). You don't want to maintain all that. Instead, have a model that contains all your lists and then have a model that ties a phone number to the list they have subscribed to. That way, each time you add a new list, it is one entry in a table instead of a whole new class in your models module.

To retrieve your list of people subscribed, you can use the Django db API to return all the people like:

```
ListsTable.objects.filter(listid = 1)
```

And that would return all the phone numbers that are subscribed.

Comment: I apologize, my intentions were not made clear. I got together a list of the local cell numbers in my area. I intend to send out a introductory text allowing them all the option to opt-out or subscribe by reply; to one or multi of my clients i offer my marketing services to. But i did take your advice towards the 3 separate models, as i show above.